# I want Desktop Google Chrome Shortcut to switch focus to already existing window

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, chromium, shortcut-file

Is there any possibility to make Google Chrome shortcuts works just like every other shortcut ( create window if there is no existing one, and if it is show it instead )? What I want to accopmplish is that I want to use keyboard shortcuts to switch between programs. And I can't do this with Google Chrome because when I click keyboard shortcut instead of switching to existing window it opens new one everytime.
I was searching Command line switches here: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ , but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.